# Download a file from URL using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to load images from a URL address without the image itself remaining in the file.
It should be able to be downloaded after the file has been opened. I can't get the macro I've set up below to work.

What is wrong?

```
Sub InsertImageFromURL()
    Dim myURL As String
    Dim myPicture As IPictureDisp
    Dim img As Shape
  
'Enter the URL of the image
myURL = "https://asset.productmarketingcloud.com/api/assetstorage/67_bac06034-d536-42d1-8fdb-2bbdd8d2ce10/NGThumb"

' Download the image data from the URL
    Set myPicture = DownloadPicture(myURL)

' Insert the image into the spreadsheet
    Set img = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(myPicture, msoFalse, msoTrue, 100, 100, -1, -1)
End Sub

Function DownloadPicture(URL As String) As IPictureDisp
    Dim http As Object
    Dim imgData As Variant ' As Variant

' Create a XMLHTTP-object
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

' Open a GET request to the URL
    http.Open "GET", URL, False

' Send the request
    http.Send

'Get the response body as an array of bytes
    imgData = http.responsBody

'Convert the array of bytes to an IPictureDisp object
    Set DownloadPicture = ByteArrayToPicture(imgData)

End Function

Function ByteArrayToPicture(ByRef imgData() As Byte) As IPictureDisp
    Dim stream As Object
    Dim pic As StdPicture

'Create an IStream object
    Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.stream")

'Open the stream
    stream.Open

' Write the image data to the stream
    stream.Write imgData

'Rewind the stream to the beginning
    stream.Posisjon = 0

'Convert the stream to an IPictureDisp object
    Set pic = New StdPicture
    Set pic = stream.read

Set ByteArrayToPicture = pic

'Close the stream
    stream.Close
End Function

Sub DownloadFileFromURL()
     Dim FileUrl As String
     Dim objXmlHttpReq As Object
     Dim objStream As Object

     FileUrl = "URL of your file"

     'example

     FileUrl = "https://asset.productmarketingcloud.com/api/assetstorage/67_bac06034-d536-42d1-8fdb-2bbdd8d2ce10/NGThumb"

     Set objXmlHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

     objXmlHttpReq.Open "GET", FileUrl, False, "username", "password"

     objXmlHttpReq.Send

     If objXmlHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
          Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
          objStream.Open
          objStream.Type = 1
          objStream.Write objXmlHttpReq.responseBody
          objStream.SaveToFile "file.jpg", 2
          objStream.Close
     End If
End Sub
```

I got a <strike>runtime</strike> compiler error "type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected."

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to use the vba to make a cmd call to curl?

Comment: `imgData` is of Type Variant, but your function expects an array of byte. And although a Variant *may* contain such an array, it can contain also any other type. The compiler complains that you are not passing an array of byte. You can, for example, change the parameter type of  `ByteArrayToPicture` to `Variant`.

Comment: Try using `imgData = http.responseBody`.

Answer (score 0):

There are other post in stackoverflow like this; downloads the image to a temporary location first, then inserts to the sheet, and cleans up the temporary file.

```
Sub InsertImageFromURL()
    Dim myURL As String
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim img As Shape
    
    ' Enter the URL of the image
    myURL = "https://asset.productmarketingcloud.com/api/assetstorage/67_bac06034-d536-42d1-8fdb-2bbdd8d2ce10/NGThumb"
    
    ' Download image to temporary file
    TempFilePath = DownloadImageToTempFile(myURL)
    
    If TempFilePath <> "" Then
        ' Insert the image into the Excel sheet
        Set img = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(TempFilePath, msoFalse, msoTrue, 100, 100, -1, -1)

        ' Delete the temporary image file
        Kill TempFilePath

    End If
End Sub

Function DownloadImageToTempFile(ByVal URL As String) As String
    Dim objXmlHttpReq As Object
    Dim objStream As Object
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    
    TempFilePath = Environ("TEMP") & "\tempimage.jpg"
    Set objXmlHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    objXmlHttpReq.Open "GET", URL, False
    objXmlHttpReq.Send
    
    If objXmlHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        objStream.Open
        objStream.Type = 1
        objStream.Write objXmlHttpReq.responseBody
        objStream.SaveToFile TempFilePath, 2
        objStream.Close
        DownloadImageToTempFile = TempFilePath
    Else
        MsgBox "Failed to download image."
        DownloadImageToTempFile = ""
    End If
End Function
```